# Customize Experience Site identity verification page... or custom identity verification process?

Tags: login, experience-cloud, identity, experience-builder-page, mfa

We have a requirement to enable device activation within one of our communities. Basically when someone logs in, if the device is unknown, we want to send an SMS one-time code for them to verify. Although Salesforce allows for this, it doesn't seem the actual verification page can be branded. So it looks funky when someone logs in through our custom login page only to be directed to a Salesforce branded verification page.

If this customization can't be done, we need to explore a custom device verification solution. We can generate a random code in Apex, use our enterprise SMS API to send the message, and then have them enter the code in a custom page during the login flow. However the issue here is we don't know what device the user is logging in from. LoginHistory will only give us browser/IP, but no actual device information. So in this case, we won't know whether or not the device is trusted. I have looked into Mobile Device Tracking however it only works for mobile logins. Most our users will login from desktop.

Does anyone know how we can accomplish branding our own verification page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Although Salesforce allows for this, it doesn't seem the actual verification page can be branded.

It can be branded (somewhat). Go to your experience's Workspaces -> Administration -> Login and Registration. Here you can change the company's logo, background, login button's color and the footer. After you save, the changes should be reflected on the device verification page.