# Is a custom branded alternate MFA verification page supported in Digital Experiences?

Tags: community, digital-experience, theme-branding, digital-experience-bundle

We have a custom Visualforce page set in the site metadata for our Digital Experience:

```
<changePasswordPage>PasswordChange</changePasswordPage>
```

that uses customer-specific branding.

But when Multi-factor Authentication (MFA) is turned on the page below is presented and there appears to be no way to replace that. Is this the case?

[image: MFA screen shot]

**PS**

If I'm reading [Customize Experience Site identity verification page... or custom identity verification process?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368494/customize-experience-site-identity-verification-page-or-custom-identity-verif) correctly, this question has been asked before and the answer is that some branding can be applied.